# Why am I getting an error when trying to predict the results of a multinomial regression in R?

Tags: r, regression, multinomial

I am trying to perform a multinomial regression to estimate the impact of the oil price over an oil producer company's stock price direction. my dependent variable is "Up", "Down", or "Neutral" depending on the direction the price had given the independent variable.

Here is part of my dataset:

```
dirección    sum_profit
 Up           0.00
 Neutral     -0.03
 Down         0.04
 Down        -0.04
 Down        -0.11
```

I used the package `nnet`

I am using the function 'multinom' to perform this:

```
glm.fit=multinom(direccion~sum_profit, data=datos)
summary(glm.fit)
```

But when I use the function `predict` to obtain my results, it gives me this:

```
log.probs=predict(glm.fit, "probs")
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'sum_profit' not found
```

The variable `sum_profit` is my independent variable and is a column in my dataset `datos`.

If any one could give me directions on this, I would appreciate it as my work depends on the success of the predictions.

This is what I get when I use the function `ls()`

```
   ls()
   [1] "Petroleo"       "Pre"            "Pred"           "Pred_pet"      
   [5] "Pred_petroleo"  "cl1"            "data"           "datos"         
   [9] "ecopetrol"      "glm.fit"        "glm.fit1"       "i"             
   [13] "ki"             "kj"             "log.pred"       "log.probs"     
   [17] "mirar"          "tiempo_cl1"     "tiempo_ecopetl"
```

Thank you!

Comment: Could you please print the enviroment variables with `ls()`?

Comment: @Llopis you can see it now

Comment: Then probably you need to create a variable with name sum_profit and the data you have (the second column of your data)

Comment: You appear to have omitted a significant amount of information. Your example of your data includes a `sum_profit` column and the error message claims to want it, but the model you claimed to fit doesn't include that variable. You also didn't say what package you're using, as there are `multinom` functions in multiple packages. Please try to include the actual code you've run in a more accurate fashion.

Comment: @joran I did the changes suggested. I hope this makes it clear.

Comment: The second parameter to `predict()` should be a data.frame with the values you want to predict for. The string literal `"probs"` is not a data.frame that contains a variable called `sum_profit`. What exactly are you trying to extract here?